# How to Set Cookie in Ajax Login System

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I've created an AJAX login system in which I sent the data to login.php through ajax $.post request and it worked successfully. but I want to set cookie in login.php my it's not working why my code is as below Login.php for ajax request

```
    <?php
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/datastore/sqlconnect.php');
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = CryptoLib::g_encode($_POST['password']);
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT f_name, password from `tablename` WHERE email='$email'");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $pass = $data['password'];
    if($password == $pass)
    {
        $cookiedata = CryptoLib::g_encode($data['f_name']);
        setcookie('client',$cookiedata);
        echo 'success';

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'failed';
    }
?>
```

My Login page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
   $("#sidebarform").submit( function() {
    $("#loginbtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#loginbtn").attr("value", "Logging in...");
    event.preventDefault();   
            $.post('ajaxhandlers/login.php',
                   $("#sidebarform").serialize(),function( result ) {
            if( result == 'success' ) {
            $("#msg").html("Logged in Successfully");
                            window.location="index.php";
            }
            else {
            $("#msg").html("Invalid Username or Password");
                            $("#loginbtn").attr("value", "Login");
                            $("#loginbtn").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });

        });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I dont see you setting a cookie anywhere

Comment: don't see any setcookie statement....

Comment: i removed it.......but i added in login.php after echo ('success'); LIke this setcookie('s', 'data'); but that won't worked.

Comment: edit your question to show the actual code being used we cant fix what we cant see

Comment: I done it. but still not working please help

Answer (score 1):

Use this (or another ^^) jQuery Cookie plugin:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

### Usage example:

***Create a cookie:***

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

***Read a cookie:***

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => undefined
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It worked Guys. The problem was that the script in which i setting the cookies was located inside a folder. so i did it to resolve setcookie("client", 'data', 0, '/');

and it worked like a charm. :) thanks all for your support

[www.godesigns.in](http://www.godesigns.in)